# Selecting rows from sql table having multiple values in the field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here i  have a table 'tbllead' which is having column'leademployees' which contains the values such as

```
(450,449,451)- row1 
(450,449,451)-row 2
(455,449,454,451)- row3
(450,449,451)-row 4 
(450)-row5 )
```

then how to get the rows if my query is

```
select *
from TblLead
where LeadEmployees=451
```

[image]

The desired result should be...
row 25,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,35

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your data model.  Storing lists of numbers as strings SQL is wrong:

- Values should have the right data type
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined
- SQL has poor string functions
- Such queries cannot be optimized very well

Sometimes, you are stuck with someone else's really bad design decisions.  Here is one thing you can use `like`:

```
where ',' + cast(LeadEmployees as varchar(255)) + ',' like '%,' + '451' + ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very common scenerio where employee manage employees erds easily available.  May be this is helpfull
[image]